# Way of making odds ratios more manageable from logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic

In R I have fitted a logistic model for polygenic risk scores in cases and controls as well as a number of covariates :

```
model <- glm(phenotype~prs+var1+var2+var3...var10, family=binomial(link='logit')data=data.prs)
```

The PRS column have values from around -0.1 to 0.2

The summary of my model looks like this:

[image]

Apologies for the picture but I work in a data airlock so can't copy paste out.

I am trying to work out the oddsratios of the ldpred_beta_sum when factoring all the other variables.

```
exp(coef(model)[2]
ldpred_beta_SUM
116.549
```

Does this mean per integer increase the odds of developing the disease increase by 116? In reality everyone has scores <1 so I am not sure how best to interpret this? Would it be better to divide up the scores into centiles or the like and re-run the analysis?

Ultimately I would like to know the odds ratio of having the disease given the PRS, ideally on some kind of scale.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes: this is saying that adding $1$ to `ldpred_beta_SUM`  (and other things staying the same as before - presumably none of the PCs involve whatever goes into `ldpred_beta_SUM`)  has the effect of multiplying the predicted odds ratio by $\exp(4.75831) =116.549$

Comment: I guess I want to report at as just a 0.1 increase or similar , do I literally just divide by as much?

Comment: It is a little more complicated: it would be multiplying by $\exp(4.75831 \times 0.1) = {116.549}^{0.1}\approx 1.60935$, a much smaller number

Comment: Ah okay cool. And how would I generate confidence intervals for these smaller graduations?

Comment: And finally in a similar paper the authors state "For every SD increase in PRS, we observed increased odds for  diagnosis of a factor of x". How would I calculate that from this data?